# Can't access bios after setting password

Tags: windows, boot, bios, passwords

I set up a bios password and now I can't access the bios anymore. I know the password but every time I enter it, the screen tells me to press [f2] or [del] to enter setup. I do that but it never enters the bios; it just sends me straight to the windows home screen. I have tried going restart from recovery and access UEFI firmware settings but it does the exact same thing, sending me to the windows home page and not allowing me to access the bios.

Comment: Please contact the manufacturer's tech support.

Comment: Are you continuously tapping F2 or DEL? Systems starting up often are very busy so only pressing it one time won't do anything. As soon as you turn on your computer start tapping F2 or DEL over and over until it enters BIOS.